# Duplicate test execution when run gradle test

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

When I run `>gradle test` all the BDD test steps are executed twice. I created the project using intelliJ as my IDE and following are the task that could see under `Gradle tasks` window.

I choose command line to run the tests with above command

[image]

In my `build.gradle` I don't have test task defined

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "idea"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

def version = [
        'groovy'    : '1.8.6',
        'junit'     : '4.10',
        'geb'       : '0.7.2',
        'selenium'  : '2.25.0',
        'cucumber'  : '1.0.8'
]

ext.drivers = ["htmlunit", "firefox", "chrome"]

dependencies {

    groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$version.groovy"

    testCompile "junit:junit:$version.junit"
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-junit4:$version.geb"

    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-groovy:$version.cucumber"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:$version.cucumber"

    // Drivers
    drivers.each { driver ->
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-$driver-driver:$version.selenium"
    }

}
```

How can I fix this

Comment: are you using a gradle multiproject build? can you share your build script?

Comment: If you could share the output of a build run, that would be nice too. Do your run your build in IntelliJ or via command line? If your apply the java plugin you always gets test tasks.

Comment: I run thro commandline. Added build run output below. `gamS@DM81 /cygdrive/d/MyFolder/ABC/WebAutpmatedBDD-Org
$ gradle build :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 25.949 secs `      Added `build.gradle ` to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by deleting `.idea` and `build` folders and then by re-import the project.

But still curious what the root cause is.

I believe this happened when re-build the project via intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also.
There is some confusion between test run inside Intellij and using Gradle.
When I run a test inside IntelliJ then run test in gradle, they are launched in double. I must run a `gradle clean` to get back to normal.

To prevent the issue from happening you can change in Intellij the gradle configuration to specify that test should be run using gradle.

see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000191604-Unit-Tests-run-from-Gradle-and-IDEA-differ